# Stopwatch.IsHighResolution == false on my machine. Why?

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

Sorry, it is always true! Edited...

---

I've just realised that Stopwatch.IsHighResolution returns false in my machine. Why? What is needed to it return true? What kind of hardware? MSDN do not say much about that.

Machine config:
Win 7 x64; i7 930; 3x2 GB (tripple chanel); HD 500 GB 7200 RPM; Energy config CPU @ 100%

---

as requested:
VS 2010; .NET 4.0; Win form application; debug mode (I will test in release now)

---

In release mode it returns true! :)
well, sorry folks, actualy it is always true (debug and release).

Comment: And the software?  Fx version, C# version, type of application, Debug mode?

Comment: opss! At release it is true! :D

Comment: Fx = FrameWork. The .NET version.

Comment: On my machine, it always returns true, regardless of Debug/Release setting. I cannot really imagine why would it make any difference. Are you *sure* that is the only difference?

Comment: Related: [Why is my Stopwatch.Frequency so low?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345599/)

Comment: It returns false for me in debug mode only if the debugger is attached to the process.

Comment: Sorry, it is always true! Edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you don't have permissions for the high-resolution performance counters or that your hardware doesn't have that feature to back the high-resolution performance counters.

Comment: Does it have to do with the motherboard? CPU? How can I find where is the problem?  I'm logged as admin and the VS is running as admin too.

Comment: You could call the Win32 API [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx) (which is what IsHighResolution uses), and use GetLastError() to see what it indicates.

Comment: Documentation only details "hardware".  IsHighResolution is populated from the result of calling the win32 function QueryPerformanceFrequency. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx for more details.